# Best way to achieve SSG/SSR from a React based page builder

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, static-site-generation

I have a react app which works as a template/site builder(like beaver builder) which can generate react based pages for end users. The generated pages are outputted according to client side rendering. What we want is, the page should be SSG or SSR rendered for SEO and other purposes. Please suggest.